# JSF Tags not rendered as HTML

Tags: jsf

I am new to JSF and JSF Tags in my First.xhtml is not working. 
My web.xml file has following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>JSFNewProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Code in my faces.config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>

My code in the First.xhtml is 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
   <title>Facelet</title>
   <h:body>
   <h2>hi Amit</h2>
   <h:form>
   <h:outputLabel id="firstNameOutputId" value="firstname:" />
   <h:inputText id="firstNameInputId" value="#{userRegistration.firstName}"> </h:inputText>

   <h:outputLabel id="lastNameOutputId" value="lastname:" />
   <h:inputText id="lastNameInputId" value="#{userRegistration.lastName}"> </h:inputText> 

  <h:outputLabel id="ageOutputId" value="Age" />
  <h:inputText id="ageInputId" value="#{userRegistration.age}"> </h:inputText> 

  <h:outputLabel id="dobOutputId" value="DoB" />
  <h:inputText id="dobInputId" value="#{userRegistration.dob}"> </h:inputText> 

  <h:outputLabel id="cityOutputId" value="City" />
  <h:inputText id="cityInputId" value="#{userRegistration.city}"> </h:inputText> 

  <h:outputLabel id="salaryOutputId" value="Salary" />
  <h:inputText id="salaryInputId" value="#{userRegistration.salary}"> </h:inputText> 

  <h:commandButton id="userRegistrationCmdBtnId" value="Register" action="userRegistration.processRegistration">
  </h:commandButton>
  </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

I have tried out many options like changing the URL Mapping to /faces/* and including Jars in Web-INF/Lib but to no use...
Help is being solicited.... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSF Standard tags(`h:head`, `h:body`), which I give an example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
                  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" 
                  content="user-scalable=no, 
                  width=device-width, 
                  initial-scale=1.0, 
                  maximum-scale=1.0"/>
        </f:facet>

        <title>layout</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50">
                <h:outputText value="Top content." />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100">
                <h:outputText value="Bottom content." />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="300">
                <h:outputText value="Left content" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200">
                <h:outputText value="Right Content" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:outputText value="Center Content" />
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The `<h:head>` is a JSF tag (introduced with JSF 2.0) that handles the `<head>` part of your page. The interest of having such JSF tag is that this head becomes part of your JSF components tree, and thus, you can manipulate it in your Java code.